# How to save my python output to csv automatically

Tags: python

Below is the code I am trying to save the results I get from my print status to csv or json

```
# Creating the authentication object
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# Setting your access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
# Creating the API object while passing in auth information
api = tweepy.API(auth)
# The Twitter user who we want to get tweets from
name = "mytwitterid"
# Number of tweets to pull
tweetCount = 10

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
    # Process a single status
    print(status.text)

#result = {}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in status.text():
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

This throws error     for row in status.text():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: ...as the error message says: `status.text` (without the brackets) the way you use that a few lines above.

Comment: Means `status.text` is `str`. Just use it as it is

Comment: Instead of `status.text()` in your `for` loop, just use `status.text`

Comment: thank you all it works after I remove () but I get blank csv. I don't not see any records

Comment: @Martin: As it stands, this code should throw an error: `status` is local to `for status in ...` therefore check your indentation and show the output of `print(status.text)`. **Second**, the parameter `row` must be a `sequence`, looping a `str` doesn't result in a `sequence`.

Comment: ok it works but it gets stored vertically and only first tweet gets stored. Looks like I need define it as array? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just printing and discarding the things you loop over; after the `for` loop; `status.text` will only contain the last status. Try this instead:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
        print(status.text)
        csvwriter.writerow([status.text])
```

If you want to collect the results into a list variable which you then dump out as a single JSON file, use `append` in the loop.

```
results = []  # start with an empty list
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
    #print(status.text)
    results.append(status.text)

# Now dump results as JSON
with open('results.json', 'w') as outputfile:
    json.dump(results, outputfile)
```

Comment: works as a charm, how do I remove the spaces and include ',' for each tweet?

Comment: Not sure what the format looks like exactly. If that's your attempt at producing JSON, read the tweets into a list with `append` and then just `json.dump` it after the loop.

Comment: I tried below for json does not work though                                           json.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)
    return alltweets

Comment: That does not seem connected to the code in your question. Post a new question with enough details if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @Martin See updated answer with a simple JSON example now,